# Suggestions for a rotational actuator

Tags: arduino, motor, actuator

I am looking for a rotational actuator with high torque and one whose rotation angle can be controlled using the arduino control signals 
The project is an e-brake for an e-bike.

**Working mechanism**
*The control input from sensor is fed to arduino and from arduino to an actuator .
The actuator(to which the brake wire is connected)should rotate a predefined angle so that the brakes are engaged*

Any suggestions on implementing this?
Or any other alternative mechanisms for suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Suhas, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: Ok. If u could suggest just a practical mechanism for e braking system  even that is fine 

Comment: The problem is, there are many ways to solve any given design problem, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method are off-topic. If you include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see, then we can help you solve that problem. Without those details though, it is difficult for us to give you anything other than the most generic answer.

Answer (score 0):

Typically arduino can not directly be plugged to an actuator without a motor control board in between. A motor control board is just a power stage allowing higher voltage and current than the ouptut one provided by the arduino. Typically those board are controlled with PWM signals that can be easily generated from arduino.

In order to get a better answer as for the actuator you should provide a estimated of the torque needed, the desired reaction time which can of breaking system you plan to use and where you plan to break (on the wheel outside? at the crank set?)

Comment: The break would be on the wheel.

Comment: The break would be on the wheel.And well can u please suggest me a mechanism for braking ( like for instance I could use a linear actuator that moves a certain amount of distance based on control signal from arduino but practically its not easy to use that for braking )  so if u could suggest me a type of actuator that could be used in a braking system it would be fine.The programming and driving part of it I can take care of that .

Comment: On stack exchange, it is better to edit your question to clarify points raised in answers, rather than adding comments. Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. If all of the information needed to answer the question is contained within it, the comments can be tidied up (deleted).